# Vue CLI's type checking service ignores memory limits

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

DevOps has requested that we limit our frontend builds to ~1GB of RAM, so that our Jenkins instance doesn't shut down. We use a standard `@vue/cli` project, with TypeScript. However, the TS type checking service ignores all attempts to limit its memory usage, which is always 2048 MB.

I've tried disabling it and relying on `fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin` but that introduces other problems.

Based on what I found, this should work:

```
$ NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=1024 \
    NODE_ENV=production \
    node \
    --max_old_space_size=1024 \
    --max-old-space-size=1024 \
    node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service build
```

Note that I've no idea how these memory limits work, as I have limited awareness of Node's internals. But despite these, the type checking service always starts with a 2048 MB limit.

I'm not sure if it's a problem specific to how Vue CLI configures Webpack/TS.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I ran into the same issue (although in my case, I wanted to raise the memory limit instead of lower it).  I was able to modify the configuration of the `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin` by customizing Vue CLI's built-in `webpack.config`:

```js
// in vue.config.js

const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {

    // get a reference to the existing ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin
    const existingForkTsChecker = config.plugins.filter(
      p => p instanceof ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin,
    )[0];

    // remove the existing ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin
    // so that we can replace it with our modified version
    config.plugins = config.plugins.filter(
      p => !(p instanceof ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin),
    );

    // copy the options from the original ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin
    // instance and add the memoryLimit property
    const forkTsCheckerOptions = existingForkTsChecker.options;
    forkTsCheckerOptions.memoryLimit = 8192;

    config.plugins.push(new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(forkTsCheckerOptions));
  },
};
```

Now when I run my build, I see this in my output:

```
-  Building for production...
Starting type checking service...
Using 1 worker with 8192MB memory limit
```

More info on the `configureWebpack` option here: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack

To see the default Webpack configuration used by the Vue CLI, you can inspect it by running `vue inspect`: 
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I no longer work at that same place so I can't check if your solution is the correct one, but it seems like it!

Comment: I tried 2 and 4 workers instead of 1 and also 8GB memory instead of default 2GB. No noticable difference. Any explanation for this? Seems like this proposal has rather an esoteric effect...

Answer (score 13):

in `vue.config.js`

```
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
const os=require('os');
module.exports = {
    //......,
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config
            .plugin('fork-ts-checker')
            .tap(args => {
                let totalmem=Math.floor(os.totalmem()/1024/1024); //get OS mem size
                let allowUseMem= totalmem>2500? 2048:1000;
                // in vue-cli shuld args[0]['typescript'].memoryLimit
                args[0].memoryLimit = allowUseMem;
                return args
            })
    },
   //......
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. Just to be clear, this piece of code in my project was preceded by

`configureWebpack{},`

Answer (score 0):

in `node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/index.js`

```
declare class ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin {
    static readonly DEFAULT_MEMORY_LIMIT = 4096;
    static readonly ONE_CPU = 1;
    static readonly ALL_CPUS: number;
    static readonly ONE_CPU_FREE: number;
    static readonly TWO_CPUS_FREE: number;
    readonly options: Partial<Options>;
```

Comment: Disagree. One npm update - that one should regularly - and that config is gone or needs to be remembered to be redone